# Can I somehow represent list of lists in the DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Can I somehow represent list of lists in the `DataGrid` in WPF? If so, what is the easiest way to do it? btw I am unable to generate columns names by myself and I don't know how much fields will be in every list.

The following code gives me the "Capacity" and "Count" columns which is not supposed to show.

```
        var list = new List<List<String>>();

        var firstList = new List<String>();
        firstList.Add("1");
        firstList.Add("2");

        var secondList = new List<String>();
        secondList.Add("3");
        secondList.Add("4");

        list.Add(firstList);
        list.Add(secondList);

        excelData.ItemsSource = list;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the Master-Detail Pattern ?

Comment: @Aybe Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: This seems like a good start : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples#masterdetail

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use another `DataGrid` inside the `RowDetailsTemplate` of the first `DataGrid` like this:

```
<Grid Background="Blue">
        <DataGrid x:Name="ExcelData" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=ExcelData}" x:Name="DataGridDetail" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

and in the code behind define the ListOfList Property :

```
private List<List<String>> _listOfList;
        public List<List<String>> ListOfList
        {
            get
            {
                return _listOfList;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_listOfList == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _listOfList = value;
            }
        }
```

and initialize it like you did :

```
ListOfList = new List<List<String>>();

var firstList = new List<String> { "1", "2" };

var secondList = new List<String> {"3", "4"};

ListOfList.Add(firstList);
ListOfList.Add(secondList);

ExcelData.ItemsSource = ListOfList;
```

You may consider using `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` `Interface` for better flexibility

Comment: It gives me the same result -- "Capacity" and "Count" columns

Comment: You could define whatever property you want in header just set AutoGenerateColumns to false, and define the columns you wants inside <DataGrid.Colums><DataGrid.Columns>  !

Answer (score 0):

Yes `<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate> <DataTemplate>` should be used and also ObservableCollection. If your grid is readonly i.e. for display only then you  can use List also